# JNI "NewObject" will not return NULL when initialize it with NULL value?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

When I did some [testing codes](http://How%20to%20set%20the%20value%20of%20a%20Double/Integer%20type%20of%20a%20java%20class%20by%20JNI) , I got some effective answers, but I found some other problems(or just I think is).

Codes like:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL test_jni_Native_testSet(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, jobject tdobj)
{
    //Create Integer class, get constructor and create Integer object
    jclass intClass = env->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
    jmethodID initInt = env->GetMethodID(env, intClass, "<init>", "(I)V");
    if (NULL == initInt) return -1;
    jobject newIntObj = env->NewObject(env, intClass, initInt, 123);

    //Now set your integer into value atttribute. For this, I would
    //recommend you to have a java setter and call it in the same way 
    //as shown above

    //clean reference
    env->DeleteLocalRef(env, newIntObj); 
    return 0;
}
```

If I replace 123 with NULL in row

```
jobject newIntObj = env->NewObject(env, intClass, initInt, 123);
```

In java codes, I set a Integer parameter by this native function.
It seems like that env->NewObject won't return NULL, if it calls the constructor successfully.
It means that I can only assign a jobject with NULL rather than calling NewObject function and initializing it will NULL.

I don't think it a good handl.

As http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html said:

```
env->NewObject(...)
RETURNS:

Returns a Java object, or NULL if the object cannot be constructed.
```

So, my question is :

***Why not return NULL when we initializing a object by NULL value?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `NewObject` uses a non-type safe, variable argument list. If you pass *NULL* to the constructor, it will be interpreted as the integer value 0. Therefore, it will successfully construct an *Integer* object initialized to 0.

Comment: Thanks at first.  I'd like to read the source codes of JNI, do you know where can I get it ?

Comment: _" I'd like to read the source codes of JNI"_ e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/vm/Jni.cpp

Comment: Ah ha~~ I got it ~~~ Thank you ~